# What does a "No such file or directory” mean and How do I correct the problem?

Tags: scripts, chmod, continuous-deployment

I read in Stack Exchange that the message I am getting, "No such file or directory” refers to not being in the directory where the file I need resides.  The article suggested using “cd" to change the directory.  I did and ran the “chmod +x first deploy.sh”.  The result was: chmod: first: No such file or directory” the next line contained: “chmod: deploy.sh: No such file or directory”

Next I went to: "sudo chmod +x deploy.sh”.  received the request for my password, I entered my administrator password and received: “chmod: deploy.sh: No such file or directory.

Comment: What is "first" in this context? Guessing: it is part of the file name and you missed a character (like `first_deploy.sh` ) You can use auto-complet: so type `chmod +x fi` and the press TAB. It will fill in the remainder of the file name. If the missing char is a space it will also escape it

Comment: Seems your filename contains a space so you need to quote it: `chmod +x 'first deploy.sh'.

Answer (score 2):

In all Linux commands, a space is treated as a **separator** that separates command arguments. So if you try to do `chmod +x first deploy.sh` the command understands that you want to change permissions on **two files**: `first` and `deploy.sh`. I guess none of these files exists, so you get "No such file or directory" error.

Whenever you want to use a file name that contains spaces, you need to *quote* it, that is, enclose in either single or double quotes, like: `chmod +x "first deploy.sh"`. You may also quote the space itself, preceding it with a backslash: `chmod +x first\ deploy.sh`.

Personally I would suggest avoiding filenames with spaces and changing the file name to `first_deploy.sh` - it will be easier to use. It's a common convention to use underscores in filenames that consist of multiple words.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I new to Terminal.  Any suggestions for tutorials?

Comment: Just google for somethig like "basic linux commands tutorial". You can start with Canonical's own tutorial: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/command-line-for-beginners . Other ones that look good: https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/linux-commands-tutorial/ , https://www.guru99.com/must-know-linux-commands.html . You can also ask separate question here about recommended command line tutorial and see what people will recommend.

Comment: How would I correctly set up this line of code? "cd <path to \scripts\macos folder>"

Comment: What are the < and > characters in the above line? Are they a literal part of the file/directory name? Anyway, quoting should still work: `cd "<path to \scripts\macos folder>"` or `cd '<path to \scripts\macos folder>'`

Comment: Thanks for your help!